# Not able to connect to VPN 1194 port

Tags: linux, openvpn

I have set up a vpn server with service status: running

```
tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.8.0.2
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

checked tun kernel module is also enabled.

but when trying to connect to it, not able to connet.
not even from local.

How to work around it ..

Comment: Just to be sure, openvpn 1194 is udp.  You can test using nc -u localhost 1194, but you might be able to see if it is listening on 1194/udp using netstat -anp.

Comment: Look at your system logs (syslog?) after starting the OpenVPN service?  Is it failing to start?  Up the configured **verb**osity to and check your logs again if you don't see anything obvious.

Comment: able to start open vpn service but not able to connet to port 

[root@localhost ~]# telnet localhost 1194

telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused

Comment: Protocol is udp with port 1194 i have mentioned in server.conf file

Answer (score 1):

If your server listens on 10.8.0.1, you can't connect it on localhost/127.0.0.1, because it doesn't listen on 127.0.0.1. You might want to check with

```
netstat -an | grep 1194
```

If it is 10.8.0.1, you have to connect to 10.8.0.1, if it is 0.0.0.0, you can connect to any address you have configured on any of you network interfaces, including 127.0.0.1

TomTomTom

Comment: Hi Tom,

I am using centOS 7.3 openVPN **openvpn-2.4.3-1.el7.x86_64** 
I am able to connect to vpn server now.
but still the port are not telenting..

i am confused how it hapening if a service is running it should telent , status i have checked running

_netstat -an | grep ":1194"_
`udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1194            0.0.0.0:*`

Comment: @Runjeet Telnet is an application that operates using the TCP protocol. UDP connectivity can not be tested using Telnet